# Are MySQL Foreign Key auto-generated names deterministic?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

When constraints are created they are given names that look something like this 'FK5E6B788655A1514E'.

I'm wondering if the name generation is deterministic or random.
I noticed that two separate databases I was using, same schemas, ended up with the same FK names.

Does it make sense when writing an upgrade script from one version of a schema to another to make use of these constraint names?

Comment: I think you answered your own question with your third sentence.  So is your real question the final sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been wondering about this for quite some time, and stumbled across your post today after doing some of my own research.  Hopefully what I found will help you out.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html :

> InnoDB has a mechanism that monitors index searches. If InnoDB notices
>   that queries could benefit from building a hash index, it does so
>   automatically. This feature is enabled by the
>   innodb_adaptive_hash_index option, or turned off by the
>   --skip-innodb_adaptive_hash_index at server startup.

The reason for implementation of this feature is explained here:

> If a table fits almost entirely in main memory, a hash index can speed
>   up queries by enabling direct lookup of any element, turning the index
>   value into a sort of pointer.

More on the adaptive_hash_index can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_adaptive_hash_index

In there, they explain the actual generation of the index name:

> The hash index is always built based on an existing InnoDB secondary
>   index, which is organized as a B-tree structure. MySQL can build a
>   hash index on a prefix of any length of the key defined for the
>   B-tree, depending on the pattern of searches against the index. A hash
>   index can be partial; the whole B-tree index does not need to be
>   cached in the buffer pool.

Finally, there is a bit more on indexes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

After reading through all of this, I believe that as long as your db schema and engines are the same and have the same configuration options on your different environments, you should be ok using these values in an evolution/migration script.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the machine-generated names are consistent.  But this is not guaranteed behavior.  I suspect that if MySQL had some need to change the method of generating names in some future version, they would not feel they were breaking backward compatibility by doing so.

Are you aware you can *specify* constraint names yourself, to bypass the automatically generated names?

```
create table foo (
  i int, 
  constraint `i_is_unique` unique key (i)
);
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware... but! other than in an upgrade, I'm not touching the schema manually... I'm letting the tables generate automatically when I deploy my JavaEE application.